# Google Sheets - Pivot Table: how to use sum(values) in filter custom formula

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

In our attendance spreadsheet *present* is 1 and *absent* is 0. In a pivot table we show the attendance per person: sum(attendance). We only want to show people who attended sessions, so we want to filter out people with sum(attendance) = 0. I try to filter with a custom formula, but I can't find examples how to use sum in a custom filter. This doesn't work:   **= sum(attendance) > 0**

How do I get it right?

Comment: why not use: "value is greater than 0" ?

Answer (score 0):

The filter must be based on attendance, not on its sum. So it will simply be:

```
=attendance > 0
```

[image: FILTER]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see now that it filters out the rows in the source that have 0 (absent) for attendance. I wanted to filter the end result (sum of attendance is 0). The reason is that I use SUM to count present (1s) only and COUNT to count present and absent (1s and 0s). With that I calculate attendance percentage (SUM / COUNT). With all 0s filtered out everybody has 100% attendance. I'll have to make another plan.